# How can I create items from downloaded files in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently writing a scraper in Scrapy that is supposed to download a bunch of archives, extract them and then return an item made from their contents. The first two actions are easily done using FilesPipeline, but I found no way to feed items to a pipeline if they were created manually in the item_completed method, not crawled by a spider. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a code attempt we can see?

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l Sure, here - http://pastebin.com/JGp4C7Uy

Comment: Is ArchivePipeline supposed to yield multiple items? Or is it adding the results of parsing the downloaded files to one item and returning it?

If the first case I suggest trying the second.. It seems pipelines can only return 1 item at a time rather than yield multiple.

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l Er, ArchivePipeline is an extension of FilesPipeline and according to the docs it should only either return the item it got (which is actually the downloaded file) or drop it. I don't care what happens to the file item; I'll be deleting it after I'm done anyway. I want to find a way to create a set of separate items with the fields I want and pipe them to ItemsPipeline, which I can't find a way to do.

Comment: Ok so multiple items... You can't. You have to add the parsed data to the original item and then return it. Pipelines should proceed as normal at this point. Make sure you have your pipelines and their priorities set right in settings.

If you just simply return the original item does it make it through further pipelines?

Comment: Also, it would make it a lot easier for me to understand if I could see the configuration of your pipelines in settings.py and the spider that is hitting the pages you're scraping.

I get what you are trying to do but there are various reason why it could fail.

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l I only have this single pipeline, so nothing interesting in settings.
The item is returned correctly. Even if I add parsed data to it, how will I be able to split it into several items down the road?

Comment: Well my guess is that you'll eventually want to persist this data to a file or database? A persistence pipeline would be a good spot to split this item into separate components.

Comment: @rocktheartsm4l No, I'm just supposed to output those items without persisting.